# Use dynamic list to render two column table with alternating background color, HTML markup issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml, html-table

I'd like to create a table with alternating background colored rows where each row has two columns. Also, the first row in the table acts as a header and stretches cross both columns.

I feel like I'm close to arriving at the desired result but the two column list is not rendering properly. Currently, the second item in a three item list renders in the second column and is displayed in-between items 1 and 3. Also, the background color of the row does not stretch across both columns but instead stretches straight down into the row below it.

Please view attached screenshot.

[image: Issue]

Desired result

[image]

**.html.haml**

```
%div.mobileLandingPageTable
      %table
        %tr
          %td{:colspan => "2"}
            List
        - @list.each do |company|
          %tr
            %td{:rowspan => "2"}
              = company.company_name
```

**common.sass**

```
.mobileLandingPageTable
  margin: 0px
  padding: 0px
  width: 90%

.mobileLandingPageTable table
  width: 90%
  height: 100%
  margin: 0px
  padding: 0px
  border: 1px solid #a8a8a8
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px
  border-top-left-radius: 0px
  border-top-right-radius: 0px
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px

.mobileLandingPageTable tr:nth-child(odd)
  background-color: #ffffff
.mobileLandingPageTable tr:nth-child(even)
  background-color: #d6d0cb

.mobileLandingPageTable td
  border: 1px solid #a8a8a8
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px
  text-align: left
  padding: 7px
  font-size: 10px
  font-family: Arial
  font-weight: normal
  color: #000000


.mobileLandingPageTable tr:last-child td
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px


.mobileLandingPageTable tr td:last-child
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px


.mobileLandingPageTable tr:last-child td:last-child
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px


.mobileLandingPageTable tr:first-child td
  background-color: #002F87
  border: 0px solid #a8a8a8
  text-align: left
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px
  font-size: 12px
  font-family: Arial
  color: #ffffff


.mobileLandingPageTable tr:first-child td:first-child
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px


.mobileLandingPageTable tr:first-child td:last-child
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px
```

**UPDATE**

I added modified the haml but still struggling to get these rows to only have two columns. How do I add logic to crate a new row if the row has already spanned two columns?

```
%div.mobileLandingPageTable
  %table
    %tr
      %td{:colspan => "2"}
        List
    %tr
    - @list.each do |company|
      %td{:colspan => "1"}
        = company.company_name
```

This modification now has one row with a column for each item. I'm confused as what logic I can put in place that will automatically create a new row after two objects are already present in the row.

Comment: You do understand what rowspan does, don't you?  This is a pure markup problem, Sass/CSS is not involved.

Comment: I thought spanned the iteration to two columns? What is broken in the markup?

Comment: Why would *row*span span multiple *columns*?  What do you think *col*span does then?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. When I was editing the markup and used :colspan => "1" it then added one row for each individual value instead of only spanning it 1 column. When I changed it to rowspan => 2 it created the intended behavior but then spanned the background color to two rows. So I got one intended behavior while messing up the other one.

Comment: Still struggling to figure this out. It seems to be an issue with the logic in the haml seeing as how there's no logic in place to create a new row when there is more than two items already present in a row. I can do this by modifying the instance variable and creating an array with two objects in each index but this feels hackish to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this, using [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get pairs of companies for each row:

```
%tr
  %td{:colspan => "2"}
    List
-@list.each_slice(2) do |row|
  %tr
    - row.each do |company|
      %td= company.company_name
```

Comment: It's worth noting that without adding a colspan to the row with only a single column, the HTML validator will raise a warning indicating that some rows have less columns than others.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Haml, but the logic for generating your table would be something like this:

- Select an even number of items in the list (if there's an odd number, pop the last one off and store it in a variable)
- Chunk it into pairs (one pair per row)
- Loop through the list, using no rowspans or colspans
- Tack the odd one on at the end and give it a colspan

However, it is my opinion that tables are not the semantically correct choice for this type of data.  Tables should be reserved for tabular data (if you want to display companies, you would have only a single company per row along with other data about the company like phone number or address).

The semantically correct markup for your data would look more like this:

```
<h1>Companies</h1>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

And the minimum amount of CSS to get the list styled as desired would look like this:

```
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;


  &:nth-child(4n+1), &:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: orange;
  }

  &:nth-child(4n+1), &:nth-child(4n+3) {
    &:last-child {
      clear: both;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mosiu

Comment: It should be noted that the advantage of using CSS for this task is that it can be made responsive (ie. you can have more columns on wider devices).